# How to set up env variable in docker-compose based on an other env_variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

```
services:
  borg:
    environment:
      - REPOSITORY=/home/borg/borg_backup/serveur-1/
      - BORG_PASSPHRASE=${test}
```

Suppose that $test is set up in the shell that run docker-compose up -d
Obviously it is not working, but I'm having trouble understanding why as the doc here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution
say I can ?

Comment: How did you set the variable. I've used this in the past in combination with a shell script in the profile.d directory. Declaring a variable with a value and using EXPORT to expose it, which works.

Comment: I tried manually, so I did : export test=yes then I tried to do docker-compose up -d and it failed

Comment: Well it didn't failed, the container is running but when I go inside, my REPOSITORY env var is set but not the other one *

Comment: Did you try double quotes around it as it indicates in the documentation that you should

Comment: Yes I did, sorry i just forgot to write it back here